# stsadm supports just a few parameters

Tags: sharepoint-2007, stsadm

I try to use the "editssp" command of stsadm, but for some strange reason the stsadm command supports less parameters on our live Sharepoint server than my local Sharepoint installation. Compare the first screenshot with the second:

[image: #1]

[image: #2]

Both have the same file version: 12.0.6421.0

I really need the "indexlocation" parameter. Does someone have an idea why there is only a small amount of parameters supported?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure that both servers have the same search configuration? I believe, not.

This command is implemented by `Microsoft.Office.Server.CommandLine.EditSsp` class in Microsoft.Office.Server.dll.

If you look at the implementation of this class in [IlSpy](http://wiki.sharpdevelop.net/ILSpy.ashx), you can see that it checks if "search service is installed" and adjusts both the help messages and also - what the command actually does.

Excerpt from code:

```
// Microsoft.Office.Server.CommandLine.EditSsp
public override string HelpMessage
{
    get
    {
        string str = "-title <SSP name>\r\n        [-newtitle <new SSP name>]\r\n        [-sspadminsite <administration site url>]\r\n        [-ssplogin <username>]\r\n        [-ssppassword <password>]";
        if (base.IsSearchInstalled)
        {
            str += "\r\n        [-indexserver <index server>]\r\n        [-indexlocation <index file path>]";
        }
        return str + "\r\n        [-setaccounts <process accounts (domain\\username)>]\r\n        [-ssl <yes|no>]";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Although the search settings were identical, you did bring me in the right direction. I remember that last week we lowered the database security rights of our default farm administrator. When I used another account with more rights I was able to use the -indexlocation parameter. Thanks!